# How to hide certain characters from selected option's label in angular 5?

Tags: css, angular, material-design, angular-material

I am using angular material select in angular 5 framework like this.

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select (change)="viewdropdownchange($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]='this.current_view_id'>

<mat-option *ngFor="let viewname of secondMenu;" value={{viewname.id}}>  
 <span>{{viewname.value}}</span>
  <mat-chip-list style="float: right;margin-top: 7px">
  <mat-chip style="background-color: #3f51b5;color: #fff;">Edit </mat-chip>
  <mat-chip  style=" background-color: #ff4081;color: #fff;">Clone</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip     style="background-color: #f44336;color: #fff;">Delete</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>


</mat-option>

   </mat-select>

</mat-form-field>
```

But the selected option's label contains chip title like, edit, clone delete etc. I want to remove them while showing as a selected option in select box.

< Selected Option , edit, delte, clone >

How to remove the remaining edit, delete,clone?

Comment: I think there will be no clean solution here. You can just try to querySelect appropriate element in dom and assign another text to label element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a reference variable to the mat-select -> `#select` and then hide the `mat-chip-list` if the panel is not opened `*ngIf="select.panelOpen"`

```
<mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" #select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{ food.viewValue }}
        <mat-chip-list style="float: right;margin-top: 7px" *ngIf="select.panelOpen">
            <mat-chip style="background-color: #3f51b5;color: #fff;">Edit </mat-chip>
            <mat-chip style=" background-color: #ff4081;color: #fff;">Clone</mat-chip>
            <mat-chip style="background-color: #f44336;color: #fff;">Delete</mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Update**
A better solution would be to use [MatSelectTrigger](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectTrigger)

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [formControl]="foodSelect">
    <mat-select-trigger>
        {{ foodSelect.value }}
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food">
        {{ food }}
        <mat-chip-list style="float: right;margin-top: 7px">
            <mat-chip style="background-color: #3f51b5;color: #fff;">Edit </mat-chip>
            <mat-chip style=" background-color: #ff4081;color: #fff;">Clone</mat-chip>
            <mat-chip style="background-color: #f44336;color: #fff;">Delete</mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

And the component code.

```
foodSelect = new FormControl();
foods = ['Steak', 'Pizza', 'Tacos'];
```

Here's an **updated** example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xip1me

Comment: Hey it worked like a charm, I didnt know about panelOpen at all. Thanks for introducing the concept

Comment: But the only problem I get is , when I click on the select box again after something is already selected, the edit , clone, delete etc got flashed, as the select.panelOpen is true at that time and I have positioned the option lists below the select field. .

Comment: @Jaydeep check the updated answer. I think it's a better solution